# Accessing command line arguments in runtime

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I'm using the following [Vue SPA boilerplate](https://github.com/skyronic/vue-spa), which is based on webpack.

When the app is running in the dev server or as a deployed version, I'm able to make use of `process.env.NODE_ENV` to determine whether if it's a development or production build. So far so good.

What I'm after is a way to pass command line arguments that can be parsed in the same fashion, i.e. `npm run dev --foo=1` and fetch it using something like `process.argv.slice(2).foo`.

I've tried accessing things like accessing the command line arguments using `process.argv` inside the config files and decorating the config files.

I have also tried passing arguments through "env" `--env.foo` and changing the node modules export to something like

```
module.exports = env => {
    // make use of env
}
```

without success.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: So you're trying to change your single configuration file's content based on command-line arguments?

Comment: @msanford Yes, another variable on `process.env` that is based on a command line parameter would suffice

Comment: The usual pattern for this type of thing is to maintain multiple complete configuration files and choose between them when they are loaded. I'll also add that while you may want a command-line flag for ergonomic reasons, `env="foo" npm run dev` and `npm run dev --env=foo` are both equally workable in most situations.

Comment: @msanford I see. The things is that I would like 3 variations of the `dev` and the `prod` build. I thought it would be better to access a command line argument, rather than making 6 config files. But at the end of the day I guess it's not such a big deal :)

Answer (score 0):

The usual pattern for this type of thing is to maintain multiple complete configuration files and choose between them when they are loaded, even though it is arguably more concise not to.

I'll also add that while you may want a command-line flags for ergonomic reasons,

```
env="foo" npm run dev
```

and

```
npm run dev --env=foo
```

are both equally workable in *most* situations.